# How to find maximum value in each row and convert it to specific value

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, indexing, rows

I have a matrix like this:

```
0.1  0.2  0.5
0.3  0.7  0.4
```

I know that I can use [`max`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) function to find the maximum value in each row. How do I use the indices returned from `max` to create a new matrix like this:

```
0  0  1
0  1  0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
result = bsxfun(@eq, A, max(A,[],2));
```

Comment: @Divakar Thanks! One-liners always cause a good impression :-)

Answer (score 3):

**Code**

```
%%// Given matrix
A= [0.1  0.2  0.5;0.3  0.7  0.4]

%%// Get the column indices of max values across each row into y1
[~,y1] = max(A,[],2);

%%// Create a zero matix of size same as A and set the values corresponding
%%// to y1 along each row as 1 
A1 = zeros(size(A));
A1(sub2ind(size(A1),1:numel(y1),y1'))=1
```

**Output**

```
A =

    0.1000    0.2000    0.5000
    0.3000    0.7000    0.4000


A1 =

     0     0     1
     0     1     0
```